# git clone: "remote: The namespace you were looking for could not be found." ... "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: git, clone

I received the following error when trying to clone my test repo from GitLab.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\MYPROJECT\test>git clone git@gitlab.com:GITUSERNAME\test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: The namespace you were looking for could not be found.
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanting to share this stupid error for anyone else confusing the Windows path separator "\" with a URL separator "/":

Instead of

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:GITUSERNAME\test.git
```

you need

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:GITUSERNAME/test.git
```

with "/".

It might seem so obvious, but it took me some time to realise it.

*Later addition:*

I had the same error again, but because of another thing, and still, it was just a wrong URL. I tried

```
git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com:GITUSERNAME/test.git
```

although I needed:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:GITUSERNAME/test.git
```

Comment: I've always found git-bash to be the way to go on windows for reasons just like this. it lets you get around most of the cross-platform awkwardness

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case, it was because I accidentally pasted the URI twice.